# How to count repeated elements in a numpy 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count

I have many very large padded numpy 2d arrays, simplified to array A, shown below. Array Z is the basic pad array:

```
A = np.array(([1 , 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]))
Z = np.array([0, 0, 0])
```

How to count the number of pads in array A in the simplest / fastest pythonic way?
This works (zCount=3), but seems verbose, loopy and unpythonic:

```
zCount = 0
for a in A:
    if a.any() == Z.any():
        zCount += 1
zCount
```

Also tried a one-line list comprehension, which doesn't work (dont know why not):

```
[zCount += 1 for a in A if a.any() == Z.any()]
zCount
```

Also tried a list count, but 'truth value of array with more than one element is ambiguous':

```
list(A).count(Z)
```

Have searched for a simple numpy expression without success. np.count_nonzero gives full elementwise boolean for [0]. Is there a one-word / one-line counting expression for [0, 0, 0]? (My actual arrays are approx. shape (100,30) and I have up to millions of these. I am trying to deal with them in batches, so any simple time savings generating a count would be helpful). thx

Comment: You could do this: `np.sum(~np.all(A, axis=1))`.

Comment: thx. I tried your suggestion and it does work for the limited example provided. However if the first element of array A is [0, 1, 2], then this is counted as a 'pad', due to the first zero when only full pads [0, 0, 0] should be counted. That may be what you are commenting on below. thx

Comment: Yep, I specifically was assuming `A` had no zeros and that `Z` was always zeros. I didn't think submitting my comment as an answer was worth it given those constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> np.equal(A, Z).all(axis=1).sum()
3
```

Step by step:

```
>>> np.equal(A, Z)
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])

>>> np.equal(A, Z).all(axis=1)
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True])

>>> np.equal(A, Z).all(axis=1).sum()
3
```

Comment: OP, this is a great answer if your 'padding' array `Z` is not necessarily zeros. My comment specifically would only work for rows of zeros.

Comment: Starting with `A == Z` also seems to work, is there a problem with it? (I don't know much numpy)

Comment: @KellyBundy. No there is no problem to do that but I prefer chained functions `np.equal(A, Z).all(axis=1)` rather than `(A == Z).all(axis=1)`. Just a question of readability (IMHO). From the documentation of `np.equal`: *Return (x1 == x2) element-wise.*

Comment: Thanks. I had looked at the doc, but the extra "element-wise" threw me off (whenever something extra is said, I expect it to make a difference).